# Login Activity has leaked window

Tags: java, android, exception, dialog, memory-leaks

I know that that exception comes out of a dialog that wasn't dismissed.

Here's the activity that crashes the application (**The following code is the main part of the activity, the others are just little functions (with no dialogs)**:

```
 public void facebookLogin()
{
    shareAppPreferences = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
     facebook =  new Facebook("something");//((GlobalVars)getApplicationContext()).facebook;

     String access_token = shareAppPreferences.getAccessToken();
     Long expires = shareAppPreferences.getAccessExpires();
     Log.d("MyTag","token:" +access_token);
     if(access_token != null) {
         facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
     }
     if(expires != 0) {
         facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
     }
     /*
      * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
      */
     if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
         Log.d("MyTag","In Authorize");
          facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream", "email"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {
              public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                  shareAppPreferences.saveAccessToken(facebook.getAccessToken());
                  Log.d("MyTag","face token: " +facebook.getAccessToken());
                  shareAppPreferences.saveAccessExpires(facebook.getAccessExpires());

              }

              public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFacebookError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onCancel() {

          }
          });
     }
     new AccessKeyTask().execute("someURL");
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
     Log.d("MyTag", "starting activity");
     startActivity(intent);

}
```

Here's the Logcat exception part:

```
    11-22 18:32:06.484: I/MapActivity(19687): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
11-22 18:32:06.488: E/MapActivity(19687): Couldn't get connection factory client
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687): Activity com.inturnex.allaround.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4055d560 that was originally added here
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.inturnex.allaround.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4055d560 that was originally added here
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:260)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.dialog(Facebook.java:839)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.startDialogAuth(Facebook.java:368)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:231)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at com.inturnex.allaround.Login.facebookLogin(Login.java:147)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at com.inturnex.allaround.Login.onCreate(Login.java:55)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1628)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 18:32:07.402: D/PhoneWindow(19687): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view android.widget.RelativeLayout@40593b28 has no id.
11-22 18:32:07.402: D/PhoneWindow(19687): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view android.widget.RelativeLayout@40593b28 has no id.
```

Comment: Not that it will fix your issue, but try replacing `getApplicationContext()` with `getBaseContext()`. Even better, assign `getBaseContext()` to a variable and use it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're session is not valid, you're entering that if statement and performing some Facebook login code, which opens a dialog. You're not stopping the progress of the code and as such this block will still run, even though it shouldn't until the Facebook authentication is finished.

```
 new AccessKeyTask().execute("someURL");
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
 Log.d("MyTag", "starting activity");
 startActivity(intent);
```

I'd suggest putting this code into a function called `completeLogin` or something and adding the call to your `onComplete` and also add an `else` to your session conditional which calls `completeLogin` also.

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't notice it.. Fixed my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

what happens in line 147? `11-22 18:32:06.707: E/WindowManager(19687):     at com.inturnex.allaround.Login.facebookLogin(Login.java:147)`

my suspicion is that one of the errors are being called and you are trying to show a `Toast` after the UI thread has closed.

try using `runOnUIThread()`

Comment: in like 147 there is the facebook.authorize(...). that line of code is displayed above in the code snippet.